# Extracting date from XML field in SparkSQL

Tags: xpath, apache-spark-sql

I have a SQL table with a field called `xml` where a `XML` structure is stored as a string.

I would like to extract this as a string/date somehow. There are multiple days/months/years and I only want to extract the first one. To extract just the `day` the following works fine:

```
SELECT explode(xpath(xml, '(//Day/text())[1]')) FROM table_name
```

I could do this for month and year and then concate everything. But how can I do it with one select query? I tried using concat:

```
SELECT explode(xpath(xml, 'concat((//Day/text())[1], (//Month/text())[1]')) FROM table_name
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Can not convert #STRING to a NodeList
```

Comment: isn't `explode` redundant?

Comment: @ConalTuohy Sorry, not the best person to answer this. When I did not use explode the results were returned as an array, which I did not want. And I only learned about the explode function today.